# PHP text limit with expand and collapse option

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is there any way to limit text in php and after that to add expand/collapse option?

For example:

I have a note which is 500 characters long, and if i set text limit ($notetlimit =100;) I will get 100 characters, after that, I would like to insert image (circle,arrow etc.) which will show the rest of the text on click and change to another image (arrow up for example), and close the rest of the text again on click. Kinda like page break.

Is that possible or do I have to use js for expand and collapse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function to limit the text...

```
    function gen_string($string,$min=1000,$clean=true) {
        $text = trim(strip_tags($string));
        if(strlen($text)>$min) {
            $blank = strpos($text,' ');
            if($blank) {
                # limit plus last word
                $extra = strpos(substr($text,$min),' ');
                $max = $min+$extra;
                $r = substr($text,0,$max);

            } else {
                # if there are no spaces
                $r = substr($text,0,$min).'.........';
            }

        } else {
            # if original length is lower than limit
            $r = $text;
        }
        return $r ;


    }
```

Where  $string is the text that you will be limiting to a length of $min = 1000

Now to expand or collapse text as same as google plus do, us can use the **truncate.js** file.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in plain PHP (page reload required for text expansion, not SEO friendly), in plain JS (e.g. with [jQuery Expander](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/)) or you can use a mixture of both: create the HTML-markup in PHP and use JS to switch between the expanded and collapsed versions.

Doing it in plain JS and not changing the HTML markup would be considered the most up to date method by most people ([Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)) - but there are arguments for every solution.

Comment: Thanks, I will try with Expander.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. You could generate a link like

```
<a href='...?offset=100'><img src='...arrow.png'/></a>
```

if the text you have is longer than `$notelimit`. And then if the link is clicked you check for `$_GET["offset"]` and show the note from that offset with

```
substr($notetext, $offset);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php for more info!

Answer (score 0):

function myTrace($string,$initialVal,$strPad)

```
{
    $lengh = strlen($string);

    if($lengh>$initialVal){

        $tracedString = substr($string,0, $initialVal).$strPad;

    }else{

       $tracedString = $string;

    }

    return ucfirst($tracedString);
}
```

$text = "Helloworld";

$result = myTrace($text,5,'...');

echo $result;//output is hello...

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like

```
$note = "some note goes here";
$noteLimit = 100;
if(strlen($note) > $noteLimit)
{
    RenderCollapsedNote($note);
}
else
{
    RenderFullNote($note);
}
```

Now the functions RenderCollapsedNote and RenderFullNote generate the container for your note. Doing this realtime with a text input on the page would require you to post the note back (on keypress) with javascript/ajax and update the page according to the response. However I would highly recommend a javascript only approach as it will be far more efficient than this.